# Background img not displaying

Tags: html, css, class, background, stylesheet

my background image is not displaying at all and I can't debug it. I tried turning it into a ID, class, and so on but nothing works. Is there something I am obviously not seeing?

HTML code:

```
<title>Temple-Digital Designer</title>

<!--This links my bootstrap css file -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--This links my stylesheet from the css folder in portfolio-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">

<!--This links my jQuery file-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
 <div class="container-fluid header-section">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid what-i-do">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid about-me">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid contact-me">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid footer-section">

</div>




<!--Defines my javascript file(local made one) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/helper.js"></script>
</body>
```

My CSS code:

```
.header-section {

    background-image: url('../img/pineapple.jpg');

    width: 100%;

    height: 400px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-size: contain;

}
```

Don't mind the jquery libraries, I was planning on using them later with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have not set proper background path. I used online absolute path and it is working fine.

```css
.header-section {
 background-image:url('http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2014/07/Shiny-eco-style-green-background-vector-01.jpg');

width: 100%;

height: 400px;

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<title>Temple-Digital Designer</title>

<!--This links my bootstrap css file -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--This links my stylesheet from the css folder in portfolio-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">

<!--This links my jQuery file-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid header-section">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid what-i-do">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid about-me">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid contact-me">

</div>



<div class="container-fluid footer-section">

</div>




<!--Defines my javascript file(local made one) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/helper.js"></script>
</body>
```

and you can see [codepen link here](http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/EgpNJq)

Answer (score 0):

Check your path.
If path is true set `background-size:cover`.it may be true.